# Issue with authenticating against Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to authenticate an asp.net core 2 application using Azure AD.  It works fine locally.  Unfortunately when I publish it to Azure, I keep running into issues.

I keep getting this error:
AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:

No matter what I change in Azure and the code, I'm not able to get it to work.

In Azure AD, I have the same values set as the reply urls.

In App registrations (Preview), the app has the same reply urls.

I'm not sure if this is causing the issue or not. The application and AD are on different Azure instances.  I've checked and the Application has the correct Azure AD ClientId.

Is there anything else I can do/try?

This is what my app.config looks like:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "companyname.com",
"TenantId": "b1234",
"ClientId": "a1234",
//"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
"CallbackPath": "http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc"
//"CallbackPath": "https://localhost:44330/signin-oidc"
},
```

According to everything that I've read, this should be working.

Comment: Check the `redirect_uri` parameter in the URL when you get the error. Check if that matches what you have configured.

Comment: When I go to http://mysite.azurewebsite.net, I'm getting this as the uri:https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&client_id=a1234    Should I try that as the return url?

Answer (score 0):

The callback url is used in [Azure APP service's built-in authentication (Easy Auth)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) .

So the first attempt is disable the Easy Auth :

1. In the Azure portal, navigate to your App Service app. In the left navigation, select `Authentication / Authorization`.
2. Make `App Service Authentication` OFF.

Then you application will take over the authentication process.